# Editing Immutable Strings in C- worked with older compiler but breaks with modern one

Tags: c, solaris, cc

I am working with some ancient legacy code that was running on Solaris 10.  On the old server, the code compiled and ran without trouble.

The code was then migrated to a Solaris 11 server, where the code still compiles, but when it runs it creates a seg fault core dump.

In both cases, the compiler used was /opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc.

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char   *blank = "                                   ";

main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{

blank[35] = '\0';
printf("Success.\n");

}
```

This worked on the Solaris 10, but causes a Segmenation Fault (core dumped) on the Solaris 11.
Normally I'd say the segfault is being caused by trying to write to blank[35] when the blank[] array only goes up to blank[34] (it is initialized with 35 space characters), except this code worked on the Solaris 10.

Also, when I change the line to 'blank[34] = '\0';' on the new server, I still get a segfault core dump.

When I change blank to a normal array (and also modernize main), everything works fine, as I'd expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char blank[35];

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

  int i;

  for (i=0; i<34; i++)
  {
   blank[i] = ' ';
  }

  blank[34] = '\0';
  printf("Success.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

What I really need to know is why this code ran okay on the old server, and what am I overlooking?  I can change the code to use a normal array to make it run on the new server, but what sort of problems might that cause?

Comment: Is modifying a character constant like that undefined behaviour?

Comment: In later C compilers, a literal string such as `"  ...  "` is considered immutable. It may have been allowed in an ancient version of C from Solaris 10. (That syntax of declaring the types of arguments outside of the parentheses goes back to the Cretaceous period.)

Comment: regarding; `main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv;`  1) modern compilers will not assume a return type of `int`,  so must explicity write the `int`  2) placing the parameter definitions after the signature of a function was ok, 20 years ago, Most modern compilers still support that, but you should be writing it as: `int main( int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: regarding; `char   *blank = "                                   ";`  This puts the array pointed to by `blank` in readonly memory, so it cannot be modified with out causing a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `blank[35] = '\0';` in a modern compiler, this is trying to modify readonly memory, which causes a seg fault event

Comment: Changing a string literal has always been *undefined behaviour* as per the standard. That does not mean that a core dump is the observable behaviour. Apparently on your old server, changing a string literal does what would be expected (though, as far as C is concerned, it is *UB* (and should be avoided)).

Comment: undefined behavior means it can do whatever it likes, including working seemingly correctly sometimes.

Comment: what compilers and versions and what does the disassembly show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they using the exact same version of the C compiler and exact same flags?

Older versions of the Studio compilers (/opt/SUNWspro/...) put constant strings in writable memory by default, unless you used the `-features=conststrings` flag to put them in read-only memory.

Later versions of the Studio compilers made `-features=conststrings` the default and require `-features=no%conststrings` to make them writable again, as shown in the Studio 12.6 docs at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77788/bjapr.html#OSSCGbjaqo.

This is similar to what gcc has done with the equivalent flag `-fwritable-strings` which was on by default in the oldest versions, then was turned off by default in
several releases, before being [removed in gcc 4.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html), making constant strings always
in read-only memory.

Comment: Thank you!  Re-compiling the code using the `-features=no%conststrings` flag made all the code work perfectly!  This not only explains why the code used to work and no longer doesn't, but provides a quick solution- one change to my makefile, and now ALL the code is working (this changing string literal nonsense occurs in several places).  This is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Take note that you do not have `char blank[]`, but rather `char *blank`, which is pointing to a String Literal.  String literals are immutable.  This code is attempting to modify one of the characters of the literal pointed to by `blank`, resulting in Undefined Behavior.  The funny thing about Undefined Behavior is that it can do anything, including function the way you intended it to.

It is also worth noting the string literal is already implicitly null-terminated, so explicitly adding '\0' at the end is unnecessary regardless.

Comment: I agree completely, which is why the fact that this code ran successfully is baffling to me. My question is why would this code WORK, not why doesn't it work (because it shouldn't work).

Comment: Undefined Behavior (assuming it was undefined in the K&R days; I'm mostly familiar with the ANSI/ISO standards) can result in anything, including code that works as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is not the OS version, but rather the compiler you built the code with.  There are lots of problems with this code, and it's easy to see how it might work on one compiler but not another.  Given that we don't know what compiler you're using, I'm not going to speculate.

But I'll bet you a coffee that if the machines have the same hardware architecture (e.g. both ultrasparc) that if you compile your binary on Solaris 10 that it'll run just fine on Solaris 11.